# Microsoft Authentication and Access token Validation in Backend?

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication

Suppose for frontend I am using microsoft authentication in React app. After Login one access token will be generated. For Backend i have  springboot there i have implemented jwt based authentication .To access the protected routes needs token. As when user log's in using microsoft I want to validate access token in backend(Spring Boot). After validation I will generate jwt to access protected Routes. So, How to validate the access token in Backend?